# Does a setInterval function keep running even when the event listener it's bound to is unbound?

Tags: coffeescript, jplayer

I have the following code:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").on $.jPlayer.event.play, (evt) =>
  @trackListening()

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").on $.jPlayer.event.pause, (evt) =>
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").unbind $.jPlayer.event.play


trackListening: () ->
  callback = -> doSomething
  setInterval callback, 10000
```

I would think that calling unbind on the $.jPlayer.event.play listener would remove all functions attached to that event listener when jPlayer is paused and stop TrackListening from being fired but it keeps running after the fact. Is it because I have a setInterval that will run continuously despite the listener being unbound? Would I need to call some function that would stop the setInterval from running inside the pause event?

Comment: yes.you have a call `clearInterval()` for it to stop

Answer (score 0):

I had a feeling it was the setInterval causing the issue. @agconti is correct in that I had to call a clearInterval() to make it stop.